# PyQt WebEngine crashes

Tags: pyqt, crash, qwebengineview

I have a browser with everything. But suddendly out of no where it stardet crashing randomly.

Heres a sample i tried it with.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QPushButton, QDockWidget
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, Qt

class BrowserWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.google.com"))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = BrowserWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

And heres a video of the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwAbk2ZpdXU

The output of the console was not relevant(i think, but i am not sure) you can see that the last to console launches didnt have it and they still crashed.

Comment: It could be literally anything, including hardware issues, windows driver updates, you name it. Clearly *something* has recently changed on your system, but only you are in a position to diagnose that.